# Is there a way to create a linked table in a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I work often in `MS Access` and I always create linked tables to `csv` or `txt` files so that when some part of data changes in a source file the change appears in the `dtb` as well.

Is there a way to create linked tables in a `mysql` database used for storing data for `php` page?

Can `phpMyAdmin` in `xampp` do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL supports a CSV storage engine.

Read the documentation here for more details:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/csv-storage-engine.html

So you can create a table that is linked to a CSV file, and if you modify the file, the new data will immediately become visible to SQL queries.

Comment: I see! Im just starting with all this so it's pretty lame question so thanks for patience, your answer led me in the right direction :) http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a linked table to MySQL in Access.  You will have to install the MySQL driver on the user's machine, and setup an ODBC.  Then you can create a linked table to that ODBC connection.